# Restricting jquery to apply to elements of certain container

Tags: jquery

I want to make a sort of try it out editor to help my students to understand jQuery better. It can be used to demonstrate and test out code. Now they will be writing code such as

```
$("document").ready(function(){
   $("p").css("background","red");
});
```

Now I want that this code be applied only to the demo code which is present in the div with class jQuery-test and not to p elements outside this container. Is it possible to achieve such a thing?

UPDATE: I guess I was not clear enough. The jQuery code has to remain the same as it is going to be submitted by the students. I want to be able to dynamically apply it only to a certain portion of a page.

Comment: `$("document")` is wrong even it works, should be : `$(document)`

Comment: then use an iframe to load code send by students

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery context selector or find() method will help to do this:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
   $("p", ".jquery-test").css("background","red"); // context selector
   //$(".jquery-test").find("p").css("background","red"); // find method
});
```

Comment: this is correct but be mindful that this will be translated into $('.jquery-test').find("p") internally anyway...

Answer (score 1):

You just have to be more specific using for example `find()` method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.jquery-test').find("p").css("background","red");
});
```

Anyway, you should use CSS instead...

```
.jquery-test p { background:red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple $("p") is the selector. so  `$(".jquery-test").css("background","red");`
Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have those elements you wish to restrict your code to in the selector.

```
$(function(){
    $('.jquery-test p').css('background','red');
});
```

this is a bit painful though as you will always have to apply it....

you might look to a plugin to achieve the goal - you will need to provide more info on what kind of things you are trying to achieve. Alternatively just get your students to use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.jquery-test p').css("background","red");
});
```